# Protect routes in NextJS using Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase-authentication, next.js

The route I want to protect: `/account`

If the user is NOT authenticated, then redirect to `/signIn`

#### Having an SSR NextJS project, and working with Firebase authentication, how can I achieve a production battle-tested proper protected routes?

The example provided on NextJS docs is not working right now: 
[with-firebase-auth](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-firebase-authentication)

So I submitted an issue: 
[with-firebase-auth-example-not-working](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/10025)

Add to that that I'm new to NextJs and also, unfortunately, I've never used JWT :( or any sort of backend protected routes cookies/JWT/sessions implementation....Until now that I want/need it.

What sort of workaround I've tried, well, something like this:

```
import Account from "./Account.js";
import Loading from "./Loading.js";
import { useRequireAuth } from "./use-require-auth.js";

function Account(props) {
  const auth = useRequireAuth();

  // If auth is null (still fetching data) 
  // or false (logged out, above hook will redirect)
  // then show loading indicator.
  if (!auth) {
    return <Loading />;
  }

  return (
    <Account auth={auth} />
  );
}

// Hook (use-require-auth.js)
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useAuth } from "./use-auth.js";
import { useRouter } from "./use-router.js";

function useRequireAuth(redirectUrl = '/sigIn'){
  const auth = useAuth();
  const router = useRouter();

  // If auth.user is false that means we're not
  // logged in and should redirect.
  useEffect(() => {
    if (auth.user === false){
      router.push(redirectUrl);
    }
  }, [auth, router]);

  return auth;
}
```

But this is all happening on the client-side....the server is not checking anything.

Comment: Is this still a problem? I can see from [your issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/10025) that you were able to fix it

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna a post a very basic answer to this. I dunno how you're going to check if a user is authenticated on firebase. My own code uses AWS Cognito for this purpose.

We' are going to put that piece of code at the end of the page. By doing so, if the user is not authenticated we will redirect the user to the sign in page.

```
export async function isAuthenticated(context) {
   // your code to check firebase authentication
   // return true if not authenticated, else return false
   
   // Maybe this way
   var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

   if (user)
     return false;
   else 
     return true;
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
  let shouldRedirect = await isAuthenticated(ctx);

  if (shouldRedirect) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/sign-in',
        permanent: false
      }
    }
  }
  return {
    props: {}
  }
}

export default Account;
```

That's it. Now the route is protected through SSR.